# Is there a GitLab REST endpoint/GraphQL solution to fetch changes requested on merge requests?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

I am using this endpoint `/api/v4/groups/::group_id/merge_requests` to fetch merge requests in a group.
However what I need is the number of times changes were requested on a particular merge request, and the content of those requests if possible.
While working with GitHub, fetching count of review comments is possible with `repos/{orgName}/{repoName}/pulls/{pullNumber}`, which returns a field
`{"review_comments": 0}` as the number of review comments on the pull request.
Is the same possible with the available GitLab REST endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread in the GitLab forum on this that could help.
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-rest-api-endpoint-for-changes-requested-on-merge-requests/77164/4